# Sequencing operator in Haskell Parser

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming

We are trying to build a Parser, but I can't understand the way the function p works, even if I understood the `>>>=` operator. How does de `p` function works?

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a, String)]

returnb :: a -> Parser a
returnb v = \input -> [(v, input)]

failure :: Parser a
failure = \input -> []

item :: Parser Char
item = \input -> case input of
    [] -> []
    (x:xs) -> [(x, xs)]


parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
parse parser input = parser input
```

---

```
-- Sequencing operator

(>>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
p >>>= f = \input -> case parse p input of
    [] -> []
    [(v, out)] -> parse (f v) out
```

---

```
p :: Parser (Char, Char)
p = item >>>= \x -> 
    item >>>= \z -> 
    item >>>= \y -> 
    returnb (x,y)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't simply defining a `Monad` instance for your parser (with `return`, `fail`, and `>>=`) instead?

Comment: @chepner no, this is from our prof. that is teaching us Haskell at University and that's the way he's doing things

Comment: OK, I might have ruined the surprise then :)

Comment: @chepner LOL :D

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see it reads three char and gives back the first and the last one as a pair wrapped in a Parser monad.

Answer (score 0):

If `p` specifically is the problem, it's working similarly to this pseudo-program, which is completely made up but hopefully illustrates the flow:

```
p input = let [(x, rest1)] = item input
              [(z, rest2)] = item rest1
              [(y, rest3)] = item rest2
          in
             [((x, y), rest3)]
```

That is, it parses three characters and produces a pair consisting of the first and the third characters.